# Why USB 3.0 ports are causing high CPU usage?

Tags: windows-8, usb, cpu, external-hard-drive, cpu-usage

After two weeks of research and a lot of thinking, it looks like my problem ([Explorer is very slow after connecting external HDD](https://superuser.com/questions/637609/explorer-is-very-slow-after-connecting-external-hdd/639299)) is caused by USB 3.0 ports.

In short: after working around one hour on a battery and then connecting power and external HDD or pen drive, CPU usage is going extremely high (at least 40-50%). With help from people around the internet, we figured out that **this problem happens ONLY on USB 3.0 ports**. If I will connect pen drive or external HDD to the USB 2.0 ports, everything is normal.

For me, it looks like it could be a software issue, but I'm not sure what I can do with it. Do you have any idea what might help?

My laptop is Samsung 550P5C-S04.

Comment: Start to remove programs.  I would go out and purchase a small cheap hdd.  Install Windows 8 on it.  I would see if the problem exists on that installation.  If it does then upgrade to Windows 8.1 Preview, see if the problem goes away, if it does great just wait until Oct 18th.  If the problem is not there start installing software you have installed on the other hdd.  Keep track of when it starts to surface.

Comment: It's not USA, in my country people aren't rich enough to go out and buy extra HDD only for test purposes :P However, I already have other HDDs, so I could easily do it. I'm wondering why given program would affect only USB 3.0, but not USB 2.0?

Comment: The entire point is to actually confirm that problem is software or not.

Comment: Ok, I understand. To be honest, installing system once again will be very time-consuming and difficult, because I have internet with data caps and there will be lot of drivers and updates to download. For now, I will be looking for a differerent solution and if I don't find anything, I'll try to do that. Currently I'm thinking about deleting USB 3.0 drivers and installing them again, what are your thoughts?

Comment: @AdamnW - Deleting USB drivers is pointless because your drivers are not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple of months, **it looks like the Windows 8.1 and newest drivers have resolved that problem**. Everything works great now and I don't have any problems with high CPU usage after connecting external HDD to USB 3.0.